# Calculate digit sum as a one liner, input has 3 digits

Tags: java, digits

I have to calculate the digit sum of a string (read in via Scanner) in a one liner. Also, I have to make sure that the input is only calculated if the input has exactly 3 digits.

What I got so far:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.print(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().chars().mapToObj(i -> ((char)i)-'0').reduce(0, (a,b)->a+b));
    }
}
```

But how can I proof in that one liner that there are exactly 3 digits?

Comment: you could Arrays.stream the full input string, then filter for matching regex \d{3} then findFirst -> your code orElse Error Message?

Comment: What should the code do if there is not 3 digits?

Comment: Just print out something like `"invalid input"`

Comment: By "one liner" you mean one statement? Because you can write any program in just one line in Java.

Comment: @Henry, yes of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this could be something like this. Line breaks added for readabiliy

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.print(
                //Make input into String-Stream
                Arrays.asList(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine()).stream()
                //Throw away averything not three digits
                     .filter(s -> s.matches("\\d{3}"))
                //Perform digit-sum (make it a String)
                    .map(e -> ""+e.chars().mapToObj(i -> ((char)i)-'0').reduce(0, (a,b)->a+b))
                //return this if there is something
                .findFirst()
                //Or give error message
                .orElse("No valid input!"));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your code in an `Optional` that uses `filter()` to check the length and `orElse()` to provide the output for bad length input:

```
System.out.print(Optional.of(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine())
    .filter(str -> str.matches("\\d{3}")).map(str -> str.chars().sum() - '0' * 3)
    .orElse("invalid input"));
```

---

Note that you can replace:

```
.mapToObj(i -> ((char)i)-'0').reduce(0, (a,b)->a+b)
```

with:

```
.map(i -> ((char)i)-'0').sum()
```

or, because you have exactly 3 digits, just:

```
.sum() - '0' * 3
```

Comment: @Jan I see your point now. I changed the filter to `filter(str -> str.matches("\\d{3}"))`

Answer (score 1):

How about this.  The lack of output indicates bad input (since you didn't specify what to do in that case).

```
Stream.of(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()).
        // three digits
        filter(s->s.matches("\\d{3}"))
        // convert to integer
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        // find the sum
        .map(n->n/100 + (n/10)%10 + n%10)
        // and print it
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want an error message, you could do the following:

```
System.out.println(Stream.of(new Scanner(System.in)
              .nextLine())
              .filter(a -> a.matches("\\d{3}"))
              .map(Integer::valueOf)
              .map(a -> a / 100 + (a / 10) % 10 + a % 10)
              // convert back to string
              .map(Object::toString)
              .findFirst()
              .orElse("Not 3 digits"));
```